# Can I change the X rotate the xf86-video-fbdev during execution?

Tags: x11, configuration, video, framebuffer

Below is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/1-fbdev.conf.

## /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/1-fbdev.conf

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "LCD"
  Driver "fbdev"
  Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
  Option "Rotate" "UD"
EndSection
```

I would like to change the Rotate values ​​in real time (without restarting the X)

ex)Option "Rotate" "CW"

How do I apply during the execution X by changing the settings of the xf86-video-fbdev in real time?

Comment: have you read the `xrandr` man page?  there are also several GUI front-ends to `xrandr`, including `lxrandr` for lxde, `grandr` for gnome, and `arandr`.

Comment: i don't use xrandr. i know "xrandr -o left". 
I know the xf86-input-video does not support rotation using xrandr.

Comment: Have you found a solution? My idea is to modify xorg.conf and restart lightdm with a script... Not very proper but the only idea I have...

Comment: Did you try `xrandr --output LCD --rotate left` as well?